# Why did Spring Boot 1.4 change its jar layout to locate application classes under BOOT-INF?

Tags: spring-boot

(This is primarily a history question.  Pivotal recommended that *all* forum discussions take place on StackOverflow, which is why I am asking it here.)

What are the reasons that the Spring Boot project used to justify moving an application's classes and dependencies from the "top level" of the executable jar format to be underneath `BOOT-INF/`?

Just trying to guess, it seems that this makes it easy to extract only the application-related classes and jars from the fat jar with a simple `java -xf the-jar.jar BOOT-INF/classes` command.  Was that it?  Was there some other reason?

Comment: We prefer to use the Github tracker for bugs and enhancements only. And questions here. But we're also [on gitter](https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-boot) if you want to chat.

Comment: If you're here because this broke you, like it did me, have a look at my answer on this related question to find the fix:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616970/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1-4-0-jar-structure-changes/42957483#42957483

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Packaging application classes in the root of the jar required Spring Boot's class loader to use an unconventional delegation model and also caused problems with Java agents.

#### Detailed explanation

When a jar file is launched with `java -jar` all of the classes in the root of the jar are on the class path of the system class loader. In a Spring Boot fat jar, this includes the classes for the launcher which is responsible for creating a class loader that can load the application's classes and their dependencies that are nested inside the fat jar.

In Spring Boot 1.3 and earlier, application classes are packaged in the root of a fat jar file. This means that they are on the class path of the system class loader. With a standard, parent first delegation model this would mean that application classes would be loaded by the system class loader rather than Spring Boot's class loader. This is problematic as it's only Spring Boot's class loader that can load the classes from the dependencies that are nested inside the fat jar. The result being that the application cannot load the classes of any of its dependencies.

Spring Boot 1.3 overcame this problem by using an unconventional delegation model for its class loader. It created a new class loader using the URLs from the system class loader but not using the system class loader as a parent – the system class loader's parent was used instead. This meant that Spring Boot's class loader would be used to load the application's classes in the root of the jar and the classes of the application's dependencies in the nested jars.

This approach had some drawbacks. The first was that it made Spring Boot's class loader rather complex. The second was that it broke a number of assumptions that Java agents make with regards to how their classes will be loaded. We worked around a couple of these but it became clear that we were fighting a losing battle.

Spring Boot 1.4 rearranges a fat jar to place application classes in `BOOT-INF/classes` (it also moves nested jars to `BOOT-INF/lib` but that has no effect from a class loading perspective). Moving the application classes into `BOOT-INF/classes` means that they are no longer on the class path of the system class loader. This means that Spring Boot's class loader can be configured to load classes from `BOOT-INF/classes` and from within the jars in `BOOT-INF/lib` and use the system class loader as its parent. Java agents can be packaged in the root of the jar from where they'll be loaded by the system class loader as usual.

For further reading you may be interested in the message on [the commit that introduced the change](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/87fe0b2adeef85c842c009bfeebac1c84af8a5d7) and the other issues to which it links.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive and articulate answer.